# Can't find a suitable substitution for this double integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, substitution

Consider the integral $\iint\left(2x^3y+xy^2\right)dA$ to be evaluated over a region limited by the equations $y=x^2+1$ , $y=x^2$, $xy=3$ and $xy=1$. [image]

I tried the fallowing substitutions: $y-x^2=v$ and $xy=u$. The limits of integration become simplified: $\left\{\left(u,v\right):\:1\le u\le 3,\:0\le v\le 1\right\}$. But solving for x and y and substituting back in the original funtion, I end up with a monstrous expression. Is there any other way?

Comment: The most straight-forward way is to not substitute, but rather split it at the intersections into three integrals. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Arthur, I haven't. Split how? I'm sorry, this is really new to me.

Comment: Isn't the integrand function $2x^3y+xy^2$?

Comment: @NitinUniyal, yes! Already edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform the change $u=x\,y$ and $v=y-x^2$ with jacobian $du\,dv=(2x^2+y)\,dx\,dy$ and your integral reads

$$\int\int_D 2x^3y+x\,y^3\,dx\,dy=\int_1^3\int_0^1u\,dv\,du=4$$

Comment: I think your calculation suggests that integrand is $2x^3y+xy^2$.